# UNION many tables, and also include null results

Tags: mysql, left-join, union-all

Seems there are a lot of "near answers" for this one, but nothing that matches my question exactly.

```
SELECT 
 'table1' AS table,
  table1.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
 'table2' AS table,
  table2.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
 'table3' AS table,
  table3.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

ORDER BY (...)
```

This works well to fetch only the matching results from all the tables.

**Example**

```
table1|1|val|val|val
table1|2|val|val|val
table1|3|val|val|val
table2|1|val|val|val
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5ad79/2/0)

However, I'd like to also include a row for the the tables with no results.

If i try adding a count column as such, i find each table's results are grouped:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(table1.id) AS matches,
 'table1' AS table,
  table1.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  COUNT(table2.id) AS matches,
 'table2' AS table,
  table2.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  COUNT(table3.id) AS matches,
 'table3' AS table,
  table3.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

ORDER BY (...)
```

**Example**

```
3|table1|1   |val |val |val
1|table2|1   |val |val |val
0|table3|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5ad79/3/0)

How do you recommend that I achieve both results, as shown here:

```
3|table1|1   |val |val |val
3|table1|2   |val |val |val
3|table1|3   |val |val |val
1|table2|1   |val |val |val
0|table3|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

**EDITED**: A few people asked for the actual SQL so they could play around with the query, so i inserted a few SQLFiddle(s) for your convenience. Thanks to all those trying to help.

**SIMPLIFIED**: A few people asked for a simplified example, in addition to the SQLFiddle(s), so this is for them:

```
table1     table2     table3
id|a|b|c   id|a|b|c   id|a|b|c
1 |1|0|0   1 |0|2|0   1 |3|3|0
2 |1|1|1   2 |2|0|0   2 |0|3|0
3 |1|1|0   3 |2|0|2   3 |3|0|0

SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, '1' AS t, id,a,b,c FROM table1 WHERE a=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, '2' AS t, id,a,b,c FROM table2 WHERE b=2
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, '3' AS t, id,a,b,c FROM table3 WHERE c=3
```

This example neglects the joins and sorts, to over-simplify it. What we'd like as a result is the following:

```
 n| t|  id|   a|   b|   c
-------------------------
 3| 1|   1|   1|   0|   0
 3| 1|   2|   1|   1|   1
 3| 1|   3|   1|   1|   0
 1| 2|   1|   0|   2|   0
 0| 3|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

But try adding/removing the "COUNT(*) AS n" query fragments to see how the results change.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If `COUNT(...)` you need to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mre]. PS You don't even clearly say what you want your query to do.

Comment: @the-impaler, i used "GROUP BY table, id" and get the same results. Just a moment, I will build a SQL for the others that are trying to help too.

Comment: Please put everything to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Then get rid of all the code here that isn't runnable. Code questions require a [mre]--which is not just code--it includes clear specification & explanation. It's minimal so--Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) ] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.
[ask] PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: The post isn't clear. It also doesn't try to pin down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sure fire way is to code each select like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(table1.id) AS matches,
 'table1' AS table,
  table1.id, 
  pivot1.field1, 
  pivot2.field2, 
  pivot3.field3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN pivot1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN pivot3 ON (...)
WHERE (...)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  0 AS matches,
 'table1' AS table,
  null, 
  null, 
  null, 
  null
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE (...). -- same where clause as above
)
```

Comment: very interesting! i'll give it a try right now and post my results.

Comment: That's a jackpot, @bohemian. You killed with that answer. Thank you.